# Vendor autoload directory error

Tags: php, composer-php

trying to do this:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

but get this error:

```
Warning: require(./vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
```

So it doesn't interpret the double dots, only single.
Anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: i think its duplicated check here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41209349/1969866

Comment: @Narayan For the record, it's working in other files that's in higher directory. Just not this one, for some reason.