# I'm unable to create a controller using php artisan make:controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am keep getting this error response when creating an controller through artisan:

> PHP Warning:  require(/home/ubuntu/workit/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ubuntu/workit/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ubuntu/workit/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/ubuntu/workit/artisan on line 18

I use the following command to create an new controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PostsController
```

Comment: Have you installed the composer packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream)

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
composer update
```

That may help your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin . i have done that but still getting same error response. i'm actually on paizacloud not that i'm running the laravel locall. is there any other online IDE i can  write laravel on?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: after running composer dump-autoload. what i got as response is as below; 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/ubuntu/workit/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/workit/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/workit/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Comment: Did you try to check your file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Install the composer packages by running `composer install` once it is completed. Then you can your make controller using the artisan command.

Comment: Thanks @ponce . i have done that but still getting same error response. i'm actually on paizacloud not that i'm running the laravel locally