# why I get 500 server error in Laravel after composer install

Tags: laravel, git, composer-php

I'm new to Laravel and git. 
I created a new project added a Template following a video (it worked), commited my changes and push it to gitlab.
Then in my work I cloned my project to my pc, then i told i need to run a command called `composer install` [require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream).

After that when I tried to run the project it gave me a **500 Server Error**, when it's clear it's still working in my home pc.

Comment: what error message do you see behind 500 Server Error?

Comment: check your .env file and make `APP_DEBUG=true` and you can display all errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will also need to provide the .env file which also contains the database credentials. By default you have a `.env.example` file. Copy it to `.env` add your databse credentials and run

`php artisan key:generate`

then you should be fine

Comment: thanks for your help