# How to make migration model in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new with Larvel and I am trying to make migration & make model so I write in the terminal `php artisan make:model -m`

I get the following error:

> Warning: require(/Users/saramuneef/trainblog/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/saramuneef/trainblog/artisan on line 18

I am using xammp for local host, and this error appears when I try to make .env file by use artisan key:generate

```
php artisan make:model Trainee
```

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/Users/saramuneef/trainblog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:')
>   in /Users/saramuneef/trainblog/artisan on line 18

I expect it to create a model, but it fails

Comment: Have you installed composer?  https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: You might check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `composer install`.
2. Make sure there is an **artisan** file in your project folder.
3. Run `php artisan make:model <ModelName> -m` if you want to create model and migration together.
4. Run `php artisan make:model <ModelName> -m -c` if you want to create model,migration & controller together.