# What reason 'Warning: require(C:\wamp64\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php) failed to open stream:

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php, wamp

1 I downloaded laravel project from github after install composer 
(intalled composer version 1.9.0) and php version in wamp server (PHP 7.3.1)

2 create database and configure db name,username and password(no password) in .env file.

3 After database setup, I used artisan command for database migration:

```
php artisan migrate
```

show error message below:

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\work\laravel\logistic-management\logistic-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\work\laravel\logistic-management\logistic-master\bootstrap\autoload.php
>   on line 17

and this

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\work\laravel\logistic-management\logistic-master\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\work\laravel\logistic-management\logistic-master\bootstrap\autoload.php
>   on line 17

What is the solution for error message.Thanks for advance

Comment: You said you installed composer, but did you also run `composer update` in the project root?

Comment: yes,after It's not working fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this : `composer update --no-scripts` 
[A stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream).

If you land with some warnings of PHP versions then you have to use correct php version.

Comment: I run this command. it show last line cmd "To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.3.1\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode." is this anything problem?

Comment: This is device & your wamp specific issue. First check at the bottom of wamp server any path issue you are getting? If yes then change system environment variables.If you do not want to get into all this , I will suggest to download latest wamp from http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ and laravel from instructions as given in laravel website.

Comment: Additionally : https://developerhowto.com/2018/12/26/php-laravel-framework/ this is for you