# How can create access token for Twilio video conference

Tags: laravel, twilio

Basically I'm backend developer of Laravel.  I want to create `accessToken` for video call using Twilio, front-end is mobile app (Flutter) backend is Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[As mentioned in these docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generating-access-tokens), you can generate an access token

- [on the Testing Tools page of the Twilio Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/video/project/testing-tools)[image]
- [with a Twilio helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#generate-helper-lib)

In PHP, that'd look like

```php
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;
use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;
// Required for all Twilio access tokens
$twilioAccountSid = 'ACxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$twilioApiKey = 'SKxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$twilioApiSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// A unique identifier for this user
$identity = "alice";
// The specific Room we'll allow the user to access
$roomName = 'DailyStandup';

// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client
$token = new AccessToken($twilioAccountSid, $twilioApiKey, $twilioApiSecret, 3600, $identity);

// Create Video grant
$videoGrant = new VideoGrant();
$videoGrant->setRoom($roomName);

// Add grant to token
$token->addGrant($videoGrant);
// render token to string
echo $token->toJWT();
```

Depending on what your Twilio Video app looks like, you may be able to do something like what [I did in JavaScript here with the Twilio CLI](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-video-app-javascript-twilio-cli-quickly).

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: (require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php') main(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: Do you need to run `composer install`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream