# Unable to start fresh laravel Project. Artisan exists but cannot run artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Im trying to start a fresh project and am following [this guide:](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/installation#your-first-laravel-project)

`php version: 8.1.9`

`Composer version: 1.9.0`

I'm able to create a project and have tried a few things like installing, updating, updating -- no script, clearing the dump, but it all turns out to me not being able to run `php artisan serve`

most errors point to the auto load on the fresh load but whenever i've `composer dump-autoload` and tried and updated and tried this does not solve anything. I've followed [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream) and cannot find any answers for my solution

Here are my reproduction steps:
visit the laravel install page.
create basic application using `composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`
`cd` into the app

`composer update`
`composer install`

when running `php artisan serve`
error recieved:

PHP Warning:

```
require(/someapp/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /someapp/artisan on line 18
```

after running `composer dump-autoload`

````
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in /Documents/someapp/bootstrap/app.php:14```
````

Comment: Inside the application folder remove vendor folder and run composer install and after complete install run php artisan serve

Comment: Maybe do a `composer clear-cache` and then do what Khaled said.

Comment: I've run both your suggestions.

Comment: Im still running into: failed to load `/vendor/autoload.php'

Comment: Composer v1.9.0 is horribly outdated - it was released in 2019, more than a year before PHP 8 was initially released. Please update Composer (even in the v1 line, there are more recent versions) and check this again

Comment: update your composer and try running your application in some other directory than the `C:` drive

Comment: you could use php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/ temporaly

Comment: Did you got any error on console while making laravel project?

Comment: run `composer self-update` first. then remove the directory you `cd`'ed into and re-create the project.